# Restframework's .save() method does not save object to the Database but returns an object with new PK

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to save a validated serializer in my PostgreSQL 11.0 Database using djangorestframework. Restframework's .save() method is returning an object with a unique PK(+1 sequence) but the object is not being saved to the database.

I tried debugging the .save() method through the Pycharm's Debugger and it turns out in the end, it does ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data) if the object is new. I checked the validated_data and everything seemed fine. When I did ModelClass.objects.create(data) manually through the shell with the same validated data, the object was created in the database. It seems that the same code is saving to DB from the shell but not from the view.

When I turned on the debugger and went inside the restframework's save() method, turns out in the end it does this for new objects:

```
        try:
            instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
        except TypeError:
            #handle error
```

My test data returned the following value for **validated_data:

```
{'strt_day': datetime.date(2000, 1, 24), 'end_day': datetime.date(2000, 1, 28), 'no_of_days': 5}
```

and after that line was executed *instance* was an object with PK 2077

I opened a shell and did the following:

```
In [1]: from core.models import UsrInDys                                                                                    

In [2]: import datetime                                                                                                     

In [3]: strt_day=datetime.date(2000, 1, 24)                                                                                 

In [4]: end_day=datetime.date(2000, 1, 28)                                                                                  

In [5]: no_of_days=5                                                                                                        

In [6]: UsrInDys.objects.create(strt_day=strt_day, end_day=end_day, no_of_days=no_of_days)                                  
Out[6]: <UsrInDys: UsrInDys object (2078)>
```

When I view my table through pgAdmin III, I see the object with PK 2078 in the table but not 2077(the object created from restframework's save() method)

Here are some relevant bits from my project files:

Inside APIViewClass

```
def post(self, request):
    usr_in_dys_serializer = UserInDysSerializer(data=request.data)
    if usr_in_dys_serializer.is_valid():
        saved_usr_in_dys = usr_in_dys_serializer.save(no_of_days=no_of_days) # Output: UsrInDys object (2077) <---- but not being saved to the Database....
```

Inside serializer.py

```
class UserInDysSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UsrInDys
        strt_day = serializers.DateField()
        end_day = serializers.DateField()
        fields = ('strt_day', 'end_day', 'no_of_days')
        extra_kwargs = {
             'no_of_days': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

Inside model.py

```
class UsrInDys(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    strt_day = models.DateField()
    end_day = models.DateField()
    no_of_days = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usr_in_dys'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return [self.strt_day, self.end_day]
```

Inside settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': env("USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("HOST"),
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
```

System Details:
-PostgreSQL version 11.0
- Python 3.5
- Django 2.2.1
- Django-restframework 3.8.2
- Linux Mint 18.3

How do I get the objects to save in the database and what is causing this behavior? Thank you.

Comment: here the `2077`  seems like your **`PK`** and you won't get that unless it's saved in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that it is saved but thanks to transactions you might not see it.
After you created something from the API -but don't create another line through the python shell-, open a Django shell and try:

```py
from core.models import UsrInDys                                                                                    

UsrInDys.objects.order_by('-id').first()
```

that should give you the item created through the API.

BTW, ensure that the API did return the result and you don't have you debugger pending. If your debugger is still active, it's likely the API transaction isn't finished and the new line isn't committed yet which means you wouldn't see it in pgAdmin.

Comment: Turns out the error was because of another serializer inside the post function and it was not inserting the data into the DB and that caused an IntegrityError and the API request could not get completed hence the incomplete transaction. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers!